# Creating an automated github issue

Tags: ruby, github, https

I've been trying to automate my github issues however I have come across an issue where the script will not create the issue, it will pull the api and all the data, and works how it should, but it won't create an issue. What am I doing wrong to where this will not work as expected, meaning how can I auto create the issue itself?

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

ID = "ID"
SECRET = "SECRET"

def create_git_issue(user, pass, repo_name, repo_owner,
                     title, body, assignee, milestone, 
                     labels)
    url = URI("https://api.github.com/repos/#{repo_owner}/#{repo_name}/issues?client_id=#{ID}&client_secret=#{SECRET}")
    Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port,
        :use_ssl => url.scheme == "https",
        :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new url.request_uri
        request.basic_auth user, pass

        response = http.request request
        puts response
        #puts response.body
        issue = {
        :title => title,
        :body => body,
        :assignee => assignee,
        :milestone => milestone,
        :labels => labels
        }
        data = JSON.generate(issue)
        request.body = data
        request["Header"] = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
    end
end

create_git_issue("user", "secret", "repo", "owner",
                 "Test issue #1", "test", "", nil, nil)
```

Response:

```
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x2e2d7b8>
[{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowScanner/whitewidow/issues/30","r
epository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowScanner/whitewidow","labe
ls_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowScanner/whitewidow/issues/30/lab
els{/name}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowScanner/white
widow/issues/30/comments","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowS
canner/whitewidow/issues/30/events","html_url":"https://github.com/WhitewidowSca
nner/whitewidow/issues/30","id":192271670,"number":30,"title":"Encoding errors w
ith recursive spider","user":{"login":"Shazgul","id":20743799,"avatar_url":"http
s://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/20743799?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https:
//api.github.com/users/Shazgul","html_url":"https://github.com/Shazgul","followe
rs_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Shazgul/followers","following_url":"https:
//api.github.com/users/Shazgul/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.
github.com/users/Shazgul/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/
users/Shazgul/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.co
m/users/Shazgul/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users
/Shazgul/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Shazgul/repos","events_
url":"https://api.github.com/users/Shazgul/events{/privacy}","received_events_ur
l":"https://api.github.com/users/Shazgul/received_events","type":"User","site_ad
min":false},"labels":[{"id":490987868,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Whitew
idowScanner/whitewidow/labels/ENCODING","name":"ENCODING","color":"b60205","defa
ult":false},{"id":458176860,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowScanne
r/whitewidow/labels/temp%20fix","name":"temp fix","color":"c2e0c6","default":fal
se},{"id":480395818,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/WhitewidowScanner/whitew
idow/labels/testing","name":"testing","color":"d4c5f9","default":false}],"state"
:"open","locked":false,"assignee":{"login":"Ekultek","id":14183473,"avatar_url":
"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/14183473?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"h
ttps://api.github.com/users/Ekultek","html_url":"https://github.com/Ekultek","fo
llowers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/followers","following_url":"h
ttps://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https:/
/api.github.com/users/Ekultek/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github
.com/users/Ekultek/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.gith
ub.com/users/Ekultek/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/
users/Ekultek/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/repos","ev
ents_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/events{/privacy}","received_even
ts_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/received_events","type":"User","si
te_admin":false},"assignees":[{"login":"Ekultek","id":14183473,"avatar_url":"htt
ps://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/14183473?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https
://api.github.com/users/Ekultek","html_url":"https://github.com/Ekultek","follow
ers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/followers","following_url":"https
://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api
.github.com/users/Ekultek/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com
/users/Ekultek/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.c
om/users/Ekultek/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/user
s/Ekultek/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/repos","events
_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/events{/privacy}","received_events_u
rl":"https://api.github.com/users/Ekultek/received_events","type":"User","site_a
dmin":false}],"milestone":null,"comments":11,"created_at":"2016-11-29T12:42:07Z"
,"updated_at":"2016-12-01T13:55:21Z","closed_at":null,"body":"### Before you cre
ate an issue please make sure that there are no issues that relate to your issue
 you are trying to create, \r\nif there is an issue that relates to this, please
 add a comment to that one and describe your specific problem. There is\r\nalso
a self help guide under the docs folder. Look through the troubleshooting and se
lf help for help.\r\n--\r\n\r\n### Issue (be specific)\r\nAfter a -s Scan on a W
ebpage, Whitewidow \"encountered an error and cannot continue\".. It totally sto
ps the scan, also outputs a bunch of encoding errors\r\n\r\n### Exact error mess
age\r\nruby whitewidow.rb -s browsergames.info\r\n[13:33:46 INFO] Found http://w
ww.w3.org/1999/xhtml\r\n[13:33:46 INFO] Found http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view
\r\n[13:33:46 INFO] Found http://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/TR/base\r\n[13:33:46 INF
O] Found http://www.w3.org/2008/07/rdfa-xslt\r\n[13:33:46 INFO] Found http://www
.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#\r\n[13:33:47 INFO] Found http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\
r\n[13:33:47 INFO] Found http://www.w3.org/2008/07/rdfa-xslt\r\n[13:33:47 INFO]
Found http://www.w3.org/\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due
 to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencodi
ng error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47
\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion faile
d due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\ne
ncoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E
 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion
failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error
\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50
 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conver
sion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder
error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89
 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output c
onversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : enc
oder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes
 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : out
put conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error
: encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error,
bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : outpu
t conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error :
encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv er
ror, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error :
output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O err
or : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to co
nv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding err
or : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/
O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due
to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencodin
g error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\
r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed
 due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nen
coding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E
0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed d
ue to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\
r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C
0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion fai
led due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\
nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x
98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversio
n failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder err
or\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x
50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion
failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error
\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x
A2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conver
sion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder
error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, byt
es 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output c
onversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : enc
oder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error
, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : out
put conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error
: encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv
error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error
: output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O e
rror : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv er
ror, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding e
rror : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\n
I/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to co
nv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencod
ing error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x7
0\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due
to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\n
encoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2
F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed
 due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n..
.\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3
C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion f
ailed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\
r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3
0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output convers
ion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder e
rror\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89
0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output co
nversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : enco
der error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes
0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conv
ersion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encode
r error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, b
ytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output
 conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : e
ncoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv err
or, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : o
utput conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O erro
r : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to con
v error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding erro
r : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O
 error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due t
o conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding
 error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r
\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to
conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nenc
oding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0
x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed du
e to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencod
ing error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC
3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output conversion fail
ed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n
encoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4
E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed
 due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n..
.\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3
C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion f
ailed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\
r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3
0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output convers
ion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder e
rror\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89
0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : output co
nversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : enco
der error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes
0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : outp
ut conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error :
 encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, b
ytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error :
 output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O er
ror : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv err
or, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n[13:37:17 INFO] Fo
und http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\r\n[13:37:17 INFO] Found http://www.browsergame
s.info/index.php?a=out&u='\r\n[13:37:18 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info
/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=mafiakoenig\r\n[13:37:18 INFO] Found http://www.browserg
ames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=mafiakoenig\r\n[13:37:18 INFO] Found http://www
.browsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:18 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/\r\n[1
3:37:18 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:19 INFO] Found http:
//www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=join\r\n[13:37:19 INFO] Found http://www.bro
wsergames.info/index.php?a=user_cpl\r\n[13:37:19 INFO] Found http://www.browserg
ames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=rlk\r\n[13:37:19 INFO] Found http://js.adscale.
de/getads.js\r\n[13:37:19 INFO] Found http://js.adscale.de/getads.js\r\n[13:37:2
0 INFO] Found http://www.facebook.com/pages/browsergamesinfo/240976396022694\r\n
[13:37:20 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=page&amp;id=impre
ssum\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2
0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversio
n failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder err
or\r\n...\r\n[13:37:23 INFO] Found http://www.facebook.com/pages/browsergamesinf
o/240976396022694\r\n[13:37:23 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.ph
p?a=page&amp;id=impressum\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to co
nv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding err
or : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/
O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv
 error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencodin
g error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\
r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to
 conv error, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding
error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\
nI/O error : encoder error\r\n[13:37:28 INFO] Found http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
\r\n[13:37:28 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&u='\r\n[1
3:37:28 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=mafiakoe
nig\r\n[13:37:28 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u
=mafiakoenig\r\n[13:37:28 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:29
 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:29 INFO] Found http://www.b
rowsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:29 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.ph
p?a=join\r\n[13:37:29 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=user_
cpl\r\n[13:37:29 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u
=rlk\r\n[13:37:30 INFO] Found http://js.adscale.de/getads.js\r\n[13:37:30 INFO]
Found http://js.adscale.de/getads.js\r\n[13:37:30 INFO] Found http://www.faceboo
k.com/pages/browsergamesinfo/240976396022694\r\n[13:37:30 INFO] Found http://www
.browsergames.info/index.php?a=page&amp;id=impressum\r\nencoding error : output
conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : en
coder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, byte
s 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error : ou
tput conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xB3 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error
 : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error,
 bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n...\r\nencoding error
 : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O
error : encoder error\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv e
rror, bytes 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\nencoding error :
 output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFF 0xC3 0x98 0xC3\r\nI/O er
ror : encoder error\r\n[13:37:42 INFO] Found http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\r\n[13
:37:43 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&u='\r\n[13:37:43
 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=mafiakoenig\r\n
[13:37:43 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=mafiak
oenig\r\n[13:37:43 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:43 INFO]
Found http://www.browsergames.info/\r\n[13:37:44 INFO] Found http://www.browserg
ames.info/\r\n[13:37:44 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=joi
n\r\n[13:37:44 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=user_cpl\r\n
[13:37:44 INFO] Found http://www.browsergames.info/index.php?a=out&go=1&u=rlk\r\
n[13:37:44 INFO] Found http://js.adscale.de/getads.js\r\n[13:37:45 INFO] Found h
ttp://js.adscale.de/getads.js\r\n[13:37:45 INFO] Found http://www.facebook.com/p
ages/browsergamesinfo/240976396022694\r\n[13:37:45 INFO] Found http://www.browse
rgames.info/index.php?a=page&amp;id=impressum\r\nencoding error : output convers
ion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xA2 0x3C 0x2F 0x70\r\nI/O error : encoder e
rror\r\nencoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x89
0x50 0x4E 0x47\r\nI/O error : encoder error\r\n[13:37:45 ERROR] browsergames.inf
o encountered an error and cannot continue.\r\n\r\n\r\n### Steps to reproduce\r\
nMake an Scan on browsergames.info\r\n\r\n### Search query if applicable\r\n-s b
rowsergames.info\r\n\r\n### Whitewidow version number\r\n1.7.2.9\r\n\r\n### Ruby
 version number\r\nruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [i386-linux-gnu]\r\n\r\n### Label
s\r\n\r\n - [X] Bug\r\n - [X] Encoding\r\n - [ ] Enhancement\r\n - [ ] Question\
r\n - [ ] Email request"}]
```

Comment: GitHub does not use basic auth. You probably want to look at the github api https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: @JustinWood I did look at that, that's how I came up with the script. Did I miss the authentication part?

Comment: Apparently so. There is a page describing authentication. https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: @JustinWood Thank you, I'll look into it

Comment: @JustinWood Alright well I registered my app, put the url as this: `url = URI("https://api.github.com/repos/#{repo_owner}/#{repo_name}/issues?client_id#{ID}&client_secret#{SECRET}")` as specified, it's doing the exact same thing

Comment: @JustinWood Would I need an ID and secret token from the account that owns the repo..?

Comment: Please don't add "edit" or "updated" tags to your text. We can tell what changed when by looking at the revision history if it's important to know. Instead, simply add the new information as if you'd included it initially when you asked the question. Readability is more important than the changes over time.

Comment: @theTinMan I edited it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

After your edits it seems like you've missed the '=' signs

```
URI("https://api.github.com/repos/#{repo_owner}/#{repo_name}/issues?client_id=#{ID}&client_secret=#{SECRET}")
```

That should sort it out. Otherwise, what response are you getting? Any status code or content? GitHub should provide you with an error message upon response.

In addition to that, you are making a GET request when you need to make a POST request (see [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue))

Change your code like this:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new url.request_uri
    request.basic_auth user, pass
```

Bear in mind you need to pass in the body of the request as a JSON string. First create the object according to the specs in the link:

```
body = {
  title: "Test Issue # 1",
  body: "test"
}

body = JSON.generate(body)
```

Then append that to your request as the body:

```
request.body = body
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

Comment: Same issue, it pulls all the data and everything, shows the information, but will not create an issue.

Comment: What exactly is the response code and response? :) It will help us help you.

Comment: Just posted it in the question

Comment: Okay, so it seems you are using a GET request.

Comment: Woops, pressed add before I was done. You need to make POST request to create. 
When using APIs be sure to take note of the HTTP Methods to use for certain actions. GET normally just lists or gets information on something, POST creates things, PUT updates things, DELETE deletes things. I'll edit my response to include how to do this.

Comment: I was trying a POST as soon as you posted this haha, thank you

Comment: Well that works, however now it's forbidden lol `#<Net::HTTPForbidden:0x2ce9140>`